# 500 Internal error while fetching large number of records from the query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that include where some join condition and sub-queries. This query returns me about 1M result. From this result I need to do some calculations and implement logic to finally output the result.

My problem is when I run this query, it is giving me 500 Internal error. I have tried increasing the memory at php.ini file to 2048M. But I am still getting the same error.

In SO, I saw somebody discuss about chunk of laravel, but I am not sure how can I implement that to given query.

Or are there any other better solutions to optimize my query.

```
    $query = User::query();
            $query->select($cols)
            ->join().....

    $query->whereRaw("customer.cid IN (" . DB::raw($selectedSubQuery->toSql()) . ")")
                ->addBinding($selectedSubQuery->getBindings());

    $records = $query->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: 500= check the error log(s)

Comment: First check the logs (Laravel, Php and Apache or nginx).

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei I get in log PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)

Comment: Have you restarted the server? Are you sure it has 2048M? Check php.ini

Comment: You mentioned that you have increased the memory to 2048 but the error indicates that it's much less than that. Check your files.

Comment: @IgorShumichenko yes i set it to memory_limit=2048M and restarted the server too

Comment: But it seems that it has not applied.

Comment: The error suggests that you only have a limit of`128M`. You can use `phpinfo()` to check that you've edited the correct php.ini file and also confirm is the memory limit change has been applied.

Comment: How to check if applied or not?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your query is returning too many rows. That being the case, devise a way to split the query into a series of queries that, as a group, return all rows that would have matched the original query.

Comment: Can you give me an example